# How do I traceroute an ipv6 address with mtr?

Tags: networking, ipv6, traceroute

I'm trying to troubleshoot a connectivity issue to an IPv6 addressed host using ***mtr***, however, despite using the `-6` switch, it fails with the error:

```
mtr -6 2001:db8:1d4f:10::1
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv4 sockets
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv6 sockets
mtr: Failure to start mtr-packet: Invalid argument
```

How do I use ***mtr*** to traceroute an IPv6 address?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ***mtr*** installed via ***Homebrew*** on my Mac I received the above error.

However, I tried answering [this on question](https://serverfault.com/q/961414/507323) on ***serverfault*** which has (at the time of this writing) 455 views, but this wasn't possible as it was closed (off-topic), so I'll answer it here due to the high interest:

### Solution:

Preface the command with `sudo` in addition to specifying the `-6` switch:

```
sudo mtr -6 2001:db8:1d4f:10::1
```

That clears the error and ***mtr*** now functions as expected.

Comment: This is not completely unusual, as mtr needs higher OS privileges so it could send custom ICMP packets as probes. Though _usually_ it's installed in a way that it automagically has the necessary privileges, but maybe Homebrew wasn't able to do that.

Comment: Totally agree, just wanted to help others- and there appear to have been quite a few- get past the error quickly, but sadly couldn't answer an existing question so had to create my own.